# How to bind DataGridView's multiple columns to a custom class's fields?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Suppose I have a simple class, and list of its instances:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
List<Class1> l = new List<Class1>();
l.AddRange(new[] { new Class1 { a = 1, b = 2 }, new Class1 { a = 3, b = 4 } });
```

How do I bind a DataGridView with columns for `a` and `b` to it?

I've found answers, but not any that work. This should be simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you have columns `colA` and `colB`, set their `DataPropertyName` property and set grid `DataSource`

```
colA.DataPropertyName = "a";
colB.DataPropertyName = "b";
grid.DataSource = l;
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not working. I'm not getting any error, but unfortunately neither are the numbers showing up in the `DataGridView`. It has the right number of cells, but they're empty.

Comment: @ispiro, it should work if you make `a` and `b` properties in `Class1` (`public int a { get; set; }`). grid `DataSource` works with properties.

Comment: Thanks! So _that_ was it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("a");
    dt.Columns.Add("b");        

    foreach(var v in l)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(v.a,v.b);
    }
    dgv.DataSource=dt;
```

Comment: But then I would have to update the `DataTable` from `l`. My goal is to have `dgv` automatically bound to `l`.

Comment: In that case ASh answer is better. It is more concise and fit for your purpose.