# DataGridView with Data Binding - new Row not showing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` bound to List of a `Class1` as in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180392/how-to-bind-datagridviews-multiple-columns-to-a-custom-classs-fields) (By the way - *the* answer there was to use properties instead of fields) . I'm then adding a row with the following code:

```
l.Add(new Class1 { a = 5, b = 6 });
```

I checked and the Row *is* added to the List. But the `DataGridView` is not being updated. How is that fixed?

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't have means to notify Grid about content change (e.g. adding or removing elements). I suggest to try `BindingList<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` (+ documentation about DataSource https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [answer to another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32182330/939213) solved this one as well. Use a `BindingSource` as an intermediate, and use:

```
bindingSource.Add(new Class1 { a = 5, b = 6 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-Assign the Datasource, in case of any changes made in the bounded source, or that are in [two way bounded](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial):

```
grid.DataSource = null;
grid.DataSource = l;
```

Comment: Thanks. But isn't the point of data binding to have any change in one reflected in the other?

Answer (score 2):

The property `AllowUserToAddRows` of the `DataGridView` must be `true`.

The `DataSource` for the `DataGridView` must be a `BindingSource`. Its property `AllowNew` must be `true`.

You can create a `BindingSource` (here named `personBindingSource`) for the DGV in the Designer by editing its property `DataSource`... The `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` might be a `List<Person>`.

So this works fine...

```
// personBindingSource was already created in the Designer ...
personBindingSource.DataSource = null;
personBindingSource.DataSource = _lstPerson;

dgvPerson.DataSource = personBindingSource;
dgvPerson.Refresh();
```

The new line will be shown :-)

This does not work...

```
dgvPerson.DataSource = _lstPerson;
dgvPerson.Refresh();
```

the DGV still contains all elements but in this case the new line will not be shown :-(

Maybe this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

you should set it following way. after you add new item in the list, you must set Datasource null, and reassign it to dataGridview.

```
    List<Person> lst = new List<Person>();
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lst.Add(new Person("X"));
        lst.Add(new Person("y"));

        dataGridView2.DataSource = lst;

        lst.Add(new Person("Z"));

        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = lst;
    }

 public class Person
    {
        public Person(string fname)
        {
            this.firstname = fname;
        }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you can also write this way - dataGridView2.DataSource = lst.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

you can use BindingSource, here I have example with Datatable, when any thing get changed in datasource it will reflected at the same time without any refresh function. If want to add new row, just need to update datatable.

```
private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = dt;
//datagridview column binding
ID.DataPropertyName = "ID";
Name.DataPropertyName = "Name";
grdCharges.DataSource = bindingSource;
```